# How do I access numeric properties via reflection in decoded JSON classes?

Tags: php, json

Here is the object I decode from JSON in PHP:

```
php > var_dump($v);
object(stdClass)#9 (1) {
  ["objects"]=>
  object(stdClass)#10 (2) {
    ["16"]=>
    object(stdClass)#14 (2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(16)
      ["name"]=>
      string(8) "Object 1"
    }
    ["32"]=>
    object(stdClass)#11 (2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(20)
      ["name"]=>
      string(8) "Object 2"
    }
  }
}
php > $rc = new \ReflectionClass($v);
php > var_dump($rc);
object(ReflectionClass)#17 (1) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(8) "stdClass"
}
php > var_dump($rc->getProperties());
array(0) {
}
```

As you can see, ReflectionClass fails to detect any of the properties. I cannot do `$v->objects->32`, because PHP does not allow numeric properties. I also cannot decode to an associative array, because that would break JSON handling in other parts of my system.

Comment: You have an odd JSON structure to begin with it would seem.  Why does `objects` property not just contain an array of objects?

Comment: Well, originally the objects array was a Map in Java, which is why it is indexed by ID. It's also easier to access the array by ID in JavaScript than looping over the array to find the specified object. I'm just wondering why the ReflectionClass is failing so bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest way is to use the second parameter of json_decode and set it to true. Using this method, you can access the vars like in any other associative array

```
$v = json_decode($data, true);
$value = $v['objects']['32']
```

if you cant change the json_decode call, you can use the following syntax to access the var

```
$v = json_decode('{"objects":{"16":{"id":16,"name":"Object 1"},"32":{"id":20,"name":"Object 2"}}}');
var_dump($v->objects->{'16'});
```

and even

```
$name = '16';
var_dump($v->objects->{$name});
```

Comment: Your example is missing the second parameter. As I said, I cannot change json_decode's second parameter to true, because that would break the JSON parsing in the rest of the system (json_decode is called once in a streamlined, generic class).

Comment: That still gave me `PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$32 in php shell code on line 1`. It was great syntax though, I hoped it would work.

Comment: then you have some other mistakes.. i just testet this: `$v = json_encode('{"objects":{"16":{"id":16,"name":"Object 1"},"32":{"id":20,"name":"Object 2"}}}'; var_dump($v->objects->{'32'});`

Comment: No, you were right! My apologies. I removed object 32 during my testing and forgot about it. Is this syntax also valid for variables, for instance `$this->{$property}`? Also please edit this syntax into your answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Well thank you very much! I'm glad that I no longer have to worry about this bug in my system.